# Don't see "X-Instance-Identity" (Jenkins instance id) in the response header

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-api

[It is documented](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Instance+Identity) that each Jenkins instance has a unique id that we can retrieve by doing a GET. I am unable to find it. For e.g. do a GET on https://builds.apache.org/api/json and see the response headers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The https://builds.apache.org/ URL has it. Emphasis mine:

> the public key can be obtained by sending the GET request ***to the top page of Jenkins***, and look for the "X-Instance-Identity" header in the response